# how to add class to corresponding menu item

Tags: jquery

I have a riddle that I cant solve.

I've got two navigations.

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">element1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">element2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">element3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">element4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">element5</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="nav">
<ul class="other">
<li><a href="#">element 1</li>
<li><a href="#">element 2</li>
<li><a href="#">element 3</li>
<li><a href="#">element 4</li>
<li><a href="#">element 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is:

When I click on #menu element 3, then I would like to addClass current to this element and also add current class to element 3 in the #nav .other navigation.

So clicking into the element in #menu will cause adding a class to clicked element of #menu and #nav .other, and also clicking in #nav .other li a will cause adding a class to corresponding #menu li a.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use .index() or maybe make an array from the elements

```
$("#menu li a, #nav li a").click(function() {
    var clickeElement = $(this).index();

    $("#menu li:nth-child(clickeElement), #nav li:nth-child(clickElement)").addClass("myClass");

});
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I enhanced Your code a little bit because the nth-child needs to get an integer, not string, so here's final demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Cynt5/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('ul li').click(
    function(){
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $('#nav ul li').eq($(this).index()).addClass('current');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TbdjZ/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Answer (score 0):

Well... in all honesty, I can't understand why you would need such functionality for menus, but...

```
$("#menu li").click(function(){
    i = $(this).index();
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    $("#nav li:eq(" + i + ")").addClass("current");
});
```

this outta do it.

Comment: I needed that functionality because I have two separate navigations for scrolling site - upper menu and small dots on the right of the page so when I click upper menu position then I need to mark it and also mark the proper dot and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

This is a very fragile approach actually, that will be hard to maintain as your html change,
here is a different approach that you might wanna consider:

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li data-menu="item1"><a href="#">element1</a></li>
  <li data-menu="item2"><a href="#">element2</a></li>
  <li data-menu="item3"><a href="#">element3</a></li>
  <li data-menu="item4"><a href="#">element4</a></li>
  <li data-menu="item5"><a href="#">element5</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="nav">
  <ul class="other">
    <li data-menu="item1"><a href="#">element 1</li>
    <li data-menu="item2"><a href="#">element 2</li>
    <li data-menu="item3"><a href="#">element 3</li>
    <li data-menu="item4"><a href="#">element 4</li>
    <li data-menu="item5"><a href="#">element 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#menu li').click(function(){
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    var menu = $(this).data('menu');
    $('#nav li[data-menu="'+menu+'"]').addClass('current');
});
```